# If $X_n$ is uniformly bounded and $A = \{|X-X_n|\geq \epsilon\}$, how to get the bound $|X-X_n| \leq 2KI_A + \epsilon I_{A^c}$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables that are uniformly bounded. From this, I would like to find a bound on $|X-X_n|$. In the Billingsley Probability and Measure book, he does the following:

Increase $K$ so that it bounds $|X|$ (which has finite range) as well as all the $|X_n|$. Then, $|X-X_n| \leq 2K$. If $A = \{|X-X_n|\geq \epsilon\}$, then:

$$
|X(\omega)-X_n(\omega)| \leq 2KI_A(\omega) + \epsilon I_{A^c}(\omega)
$$

I am wondering how the author got this bound. It is easy to see why this holds, since if I take $\omega \in A$, then the right side becomes $2K$, while if I take $\omega \in A^c$, then the right side will have the new bound $\epsilon$.

However, what I am confused about is if there is a more **rigorous** manner in which to derive this bound rather than just "eye-balling" it. I tried to do this but was unable to get the bound in a formal manner:

$$
|X(\omega)-X_n(\omega)| \leq 2K \leq 2K\left[I_A(\omega)+I_{A^c}(\omega)\right]
$$

From here, I am only able to get the about if I assume that $\epsilon \leq 2K$, while the above bound seems to work for both $\epsilon \leq 2K$ AND $\epsilon \geq 2K$.

Does anyone have any ideas what is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it suffices to show the inequality

$$|X(\omega)-X_n(\omega)| \leq 2K 1_A(\omega) + \epsilon 1_{A^c}(\omega) \tag{1}$$

for each **fixed** $\omega \in \Omega$. Now if $\omega \in \Omega$, then either $\omega \in A$ or $\omega \in A^c$.

- If $\omega \in A$, then
  $$|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| \leq |X(\omega)| + |X_n(\omega)|  \leq 2K $$
  by the uniform boundedness.
- If $\omega \in A^c$, then it follows from the very definition of $A$ that

$$|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| \leq \epsilon. $$

Combining both considerations, we get $(1)$.

Comment: Does it need to be assumed here that $\epsilon \leq 2K$?

Comment: @user321627 No... why do you think so?

Comment: It appears that if $\epsilon \geq 2K$, then for $\omega \in A^{c}$, $|X_n-X| \leq \epsilon$, but because we already know the maximal bound is $2K$, we are not using an efficient bound here since in this case $|X_n-X| \leq 2K \leq \epsilon$. Also, are the $\omega \in A^c$ and $\omega \in A$ supposed to be switched around? Thanks!

Comment: @user321627 No, not at all. Note that the inequality $(1)$ is equivalent to saying that $$|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| \leq 2K \qquad \text{for all $\omega \in A$}$$ and $$|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| \leq \epsilon \qquad \text{for all $\omega \in A^c$}.$$ (But yes, you are right about switching $\omega \in A$ and $\omega \in A^c$, sorry about that. Should be fine now.)

Comment: @user321627 Note that $A^c$ might be empty... so, in general, we cannot conclude that $\epsilon \leq 2K$.

Comment: I see, so you are saying that the inequality is written in the most general form without any assumptions as to if either $A$ or $A^c$ is empty so we cannot make assumptions on the relation between $\epsilon$ and $2K$? Also, would it be correct to say that we cannot conclude as well that $\epsilon \geq 2K$ since $A$ may be empty (using the line of logic above)? Thanks!

Comment: @user321627 Yes, exactly, $A$ or $A^c$ may be empty (obviously not both of them can be empty).